# Hidden Divs - Jquery Closing and Efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create multiple divs that can be closed with the click of a button. Being a novice at jquery, I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

My question is: 
Are there better ways to do this? 

**EDIT:** Is there a way to only have one div open and cancel out and already open one in the case a user does not close it??

```
    //hidden divs
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".x").click(function () {
    $("#tcm_content").hide();
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".x").click(function () {
    $("#bazinga_content").hide();
      });
    });

    //thumbnails
    $("#tcm").click(function () {
    $("#tcm_content").show("600", function () {});
    });

    $("#bazinga").click(function () {
    $("#bazinga_content").show("600", function () {});
    });
```

**Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0t6uqwLm/13/**

Comment: As an additional note to the answers below, you may want to look into css3 animations instead of using jquery's delay. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close multiple divs in a click event like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".x").click(function () {
        $("#bazinga_content").hide();
        $("#tcm_content").hide();
    });
});
```

And you dont need to use multiple document.ready functions. You can actually use one document.ready and put everything into it.

Working JsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/0t6uqwLm/10/

New JsFiddle for the update made in question https://jsfiddle.net/0t6uqwLm/12/

Comment: @icoder See this jsfiddle for your updated question https://jsfiddle.net/0t6uqwLm/12/

Comment: Thanks! That's simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you very much, I appreciate your time!

Comment: Sorry, not enough rep for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".x").click(function () {
        $("#tcm_content").hide();
        $("#bazinga_content").hide();
      });
    });

    //thumbnails
    $("#tcm").click(function () {
    $("#tcm_content").show("slow");
    });

    $("#bazinga").click(function () {
    $("#bazinga_content").show("slow");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything should go into the ready function, and you only need one click handler for the `x` class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".x").click(function () {
        $("#tcm_content").hide();
        $("#bazinga_content").hide();
    });

    //thumbnails
    $("#tcm").click(function () {
        $("#tcm_content").show("600", function () {});
    });

    $("#bazinga").click(function () {
        $("#bazinga_content").show("600", function () {});
    });
});
```

As to what is better, this is a perfectly acceptable way to show and hide div's using jQuery.

To clarify, jQuery uses selectors to get at the specific elements on the page that you want. When you call `$("#tcm").click...` jQuery goes looking for that element with the `id="tcm"`. If it has not loaded into the DOM yet, there will be no element to attach the click event to. That is why they should go into the `ready` function, because it does not get called until the document has loaded all of the elements.

Comment: Thanks! This is starting to make more sense.